# Cannot output json from MySQL - getting null value

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I'm using following code but cannot return data from MySQL.

This is the output:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var somethings= [null,null,null]; 
</script>
```

It does have three post, but I couldn't get the title(message) output.

EDIT: this is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

    $session = mysql_connect('localhost','name','pass');     
    mysql_select_db('dbname', $session);    

    $result= mysql_query('SELECT * FROM posts', $session); 
    $somethings= array(); 
    while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $somethings[]= $row['something']; 
    } 
?> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var somethings= <?php echo json_encode($somethings); ?>; 
</script>
```

This is the table:

**message**
Try iPhone post! 
Welcome to Yo~ :)
好快！

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information to know what's wrong. Please provide more information, and format your post so it's possible to read.

Comment: my guess is that there is nothing in the post table...

Comment: You're setting `$row['something']`, but there is no `something` column in the table. That's as simple as it gets.

Comment: Try `while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $somethings[]= $row[0]; };` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would appear that `$row['something']` is returning a null value for every row.  Make sure you've got proper data to output.

Comment: so what should i put in? any suggest?

Comment: check what the fieldnames are in the 'posts' table. Obviously there's 3 records being returned, but you're looking for the wrong names. if there isn't a `something` field in the returned row, PHP will happily auto-munge the variable to 'null'  and assign that to your $somethings array.  It's bad practice to do 'select *'. Don't be lazy and always specify the field name(s) you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `var_dump($row)` inside your loop to see what your database is returning. It will output the contents of each row. Post the results here. We can't diagnose the problem with dummy values like you put in your question. I'm going to make a bet that you're trying to select a column from the table that doesn't exist. Post your exact code.

Answer (score -2):

Try array_push($somethings, $row['something']);

Also, it is better to use ajax to retrieve data, than to directly assigning to a string.

Comment: This is just a different way of writing what the author already has. It won't solve the problem.